# Using java jre6 instead of jre7 in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, java

i need to use jre6 instead of jre7 for the sikuli-ide in windows7.

I set the JAVA-HOME to: C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_31

My path looks like: [image]

when I type java -version in the cmd it says that the current version is still 1.7

How can I switch between the two java versions? (I don't want to remove the version 1.7 from my system)

Comment: Did you check your `PATH` variable in the same cmd window you ran `java -version`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the entry for Java6 at the very beginning of your Path variable

Answer (score 1):

Go to environment variables in Advanced settings, look for System variable name PATH. Remove `Java 7` entry and add `1.6` (till bin)  there.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `PATH` variable includes `C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.6.0_31` and not java 7.